# Como posicionar un elemento al inicio de una lista circular simple, la cual a sido previamente rellenada en lenguaje C

Tags: c

tengo un pequeño dilema y es el que no sé como puedo posicionar un elemento al inicio de mi lista circular simplemente enlazada, el detalle está, en que la lista inicialmente se llenara con datos enteros, luego necesito posicionar solamente el dato menor que contiene toda la lista al inicio de esta, e hecho todo lo necesario para rellenar la lista, Insertar el nodo, mostrar la lista y buscar datos dentro de la lista, esto con la idea de que a como puede recorrer la lista para buscar el nodo, me daba una idea de como posicionar el valor menor al inicio, pero de ahí ya no supe como seguirme desarrollando.

Adjunto código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo* siguente;
}NODO;

NODO *primero=NULL;
NODO *ultimo=NULL;

void InsertarNodo();
void Mostrar();
void buscarNodo();


int menu();

int main(void)
{
    NODO *lista=NULL;

    int opcion, num;
    do{
        opcion = menu();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                InsertarNodo();
                break;
            case 2:
                Mostrar();
                break;
            case 3:
                buscarNodo();
                break;
            case 4:
                
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Saliendo de la aplicacion");
                break;
            default:
                puts("Opcion incorrecta");
        }
    }while(opcion != 4);
    return 0;
}

void InsertarNodo()
{
    NODO *nuevo=(NODO *)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    printf("Ingrese numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&nuevo->dato);

    if (primero==NULL)
    {
        primero=nuevo;
        primero->siguente=primero;
        ultimo=primero;
    }
    else 
    {
        ultimo->siguente=nuevo;
        nuevo->siguente=primero;
        ultimo=nuevo;
    }
    printf("\n Nodo ingresado con exito\n\n");
}

void Mostrar()
{
    NODO *actual=(NODO *)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    actual=primero;

    if (primero!=NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("%d \t",actual->dato);
            actual=actual->siguente;
        } while (actual!=primero);
        puts("");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("La lista esta vacia");
    }
}

void buscarNodo()
{
    NODO *actual=(NODO *)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    actual=primero;
    int nodoBuscado=0, encontrado=0;
    printf("Ingrese el valor del nodo a buscar: ");
    scanf("%d",&nodoBuscado);

    if (primero!=NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            if (actual->dato == nodoBuscado)
            {
                printf("\n Nodo con el dato (%d) Encontrado\n\n",actual->dato);
                encontrado=1;
            }
            
            actual=actual->siguente;
        } while (actual!=primero && encontrado !=1);
        if (encontrado==0)
        {
            printf("\n Nodo no encontrado");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("La lista esta vacia");
    }
}



int menu(){
    int opcion;
    
    puts("");
    puts("1 - Ingresar");
    puts("2 - Mostrar lista");
    puts("3 - Buscar Nodo");
    puts("4 - Ordenar");
    puts("5 - Salir");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);
    puts("");
    
    return opcion;
}
```

Cualquier consejo es muy bienvenido, se que faltan mas funciones, como la de liberar la memoria luego de utilizar el programa, un contador y si la lista esta vacía, pero para mientras lo he representado con un NULL.